# problem of format while using pandas style

Tags: python, html, pandas, format, jinja2

I'm currently using pandas style to custom my DataFrame before turning it into an HTML table. However, during my tests I'm getting quite the same error when I try to run my file :
`<pandas.io.formats.style.Styler object at 0x7f987c016e20>`
I don't really understand what's going on since my code is really simple and the pandas documentation doesn't really help on that point.

My code is currently the following :

````
from tkinter.ttk import Style
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [22,23,24], "col2": [44,46,48]})
#a = df.to_html(buf=None, columns=None, col_space=None, header=True, index=True, na_rep='NaN', formatters=None, float_format=None, sparsify=None, index_names=True, justify=None, max_rows=None, max_cols=None, show_dimensions=False, decimal='.', bold_rows=True, classes="test")

def color_negative_red(value):
  """
  Colors elements in a dateframe
  green if positive and red if
  negative. Does not color NaN
  values.
  """

  if value < 0:
    color = 'red'
  elif value > 0:
    color = 'green'
  else:
    color = 'black'

  return 'color: %s' % color



print(df.style.applymap(color_negative_red, subset=['col1','col2']))```
````

Does anyone has ever had the same error ?

Already thank you for helping me !

Answer (score 0):

`df.style.applymap()` returns a Styler object, and `print(Styler)` returns the string representation of a styler object as per your response. It is not an error.

If you want an output you need to call a render method, like `Styler.to_html()` or `Styler.to_latex()`. If you execute a styler object as the last line in a Jupyter Notebook it automatically calls `to_html()` but this behind the scenes.